# Windows Updates On Windows 7 in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, osx-lion

I am in the process of installing Win 7 Ultimate via Virtual Box on Mac OS X Lion. My question is simple - do I need to install Windows Updates on this virtual machine or will I be fine without them?

Comment: The same rules apply as if it was a physical machine. It largely depends on what you want to use it for.

Answer (score 4):

It is strongly suggested to install updates, since they usually contain bug-fixes and patches for security holes, but in most cases you won't feel much of a difference.

If you are in a hurry, I warn you, It can take a while, but if not and/or intend to use win7 regularly, better to install those.

Also, updates can be installed later if necessary.

Comment: gotcha! Gotta install them soon then.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to connect the VM to the network, updates are highly recommended. If not, it's not nearly as critical, unless the update addresses something you specifically care about. In any case, I would suggest periodically snapshotting a "clean" configuration. Then if your VM gets a malware infestation or something, it's easy to roll back to a clean version.